# NPE calling getLength() on NodeList

Tags: java, xml, dom, nullpointerexception

I am using the org.w3c.dom.Document interface to parse XML messages that are passed between a client and a server. Intermittently I am running into a NPE that I can't explain.

The chain of events is as follows: the client sends a message to the server in a separate (non-AWT) thread. The response is captured as a String, converted into a Document object at which point the root element is obtained:

```
Element root = response.getDocumentElement();
```

This root element is then passed to the leaderboard screen, thus:

```
Leaderboard leaderboard = ScreenCache.getLeaderboard();
if (!leaderboard.isVisible())
{
    return;
}

leaderboard.buildTablesFromResponseLater(root);
```

I then invoke onto the AWT-thread, as I am going to be using the data to repaint the screen in various ways (update tables etc) and Swing is not thread-safe. I have also read somewhere that the DOM stuff isn't thread-safe (though I can't for the life of me find that again now).

```
public void buildTablesFromResponseLater(final Element root)
{
    Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            buildTablesFromResponse(root);
        }
    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(updateRunnable);
}
```

Inside buildTablesFromResponse, I start to parse the XML. I get various attributes out of it, and then I call the following code:

```
NodeList children = root.getElementsByTagName(TAG_ROOM_STATS);
int length = children.getLength(); <- NPE HERE
```

However, this produces a NPE like the below:

```
10/05 23:44:14.505   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.nextMatchingElementAfter(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.item(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.getLength(Unknown Source)
    at online.screen.g.d(Leaderboard.java:370)
    at online.screen.g.c(Leaderboard.java:364)
    at online.screen.g.b(Leaderboard.java:315)
    at online.screen.g.a(Leaderboard.java:312)
    at online.screen.g$4.run(Leaderboard.java:305)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. There are various other places where I parse XML like this and it works fine, and as I said this problem is infrequent even with the Leaderboard. The only differences I can think of are:

- The leaderboard message is likely to be 'bulkier' than the others.
- Other places almost certainly get the NodeList/length in the same thread that opens the socket, which will be a non-AWT thread. However, I would've thought this would be more prone to problems rather than less!

If somehow the AWT thread is the problem then it's a quick fix to parse the XML before calling back to the AWT thread to paint the screen. I am just reluctant to do this without properly understanding the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously this is a very old thread, but incase anyone else has run into this issue... I recently ran into this issue myself and after some research the only suggestion I could find is that it is because the parsing is still occurring when the accessors are called. So I guess, to briefly sum up what I found, yes, you should completely finish parsing the XML before calling back.

From This thread (https://community.oracle.com/thread/2114086):

> This is happening because JAXP is not thread safe. need to synchronize bracket or use thread safe parser.